# How I can solve this error when importing aws.alb.TargetGroup using Pulumi Cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, pulumi

I try to import existing resources to Pulumi.
I execute following command on my terminal.

```
$ pulumi import aws:alb/targetGroup:TargetGroup target-group-name target-group-arn
```

But I had following error.

```
error: internal error: Error: cannot assign expression of type tuple(cty.NullVal(cty.DynamicPseudoType)) to location of type union(list(union(object({onDeregistration = union(output(string), string, annotated(0x14001d12b40)), onUnhealthy = union(output(string), string, annotated(0x14001d12b80))}, annotated(0x14001d12b00)), output(object({onDeregistration = string, onUnhealthy = string}, annotated(0x14001d12bc0))), annotated(0x14001d12c00))), none, output(list(object({onDeregistration = string, onUnhealthy = string}, annotated(0x14001d12bc0)))), annotated(0x14001d12cc0)):

  on anonymous.pp line 22:
  23:     targetFailovers =[
  24:         null]
```

I can't solve this error. Please teach me how to solve.
Or please teach me how to generate typescript code from pulumi state. Because importing was success.

appendix
My environment is:

- OS

  - macOS Monterey v12.5
- Arch

  - m2
- pulumi version

  - v3.51.1
- which pulumi

  - /opt/homebrew/bin/pulumi
- pulumi runtime

  - nodejs(TypeScript)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the docs https://www.pulumi.com/docs/guides/adopting/import/ - the command should look like this:

```
pulumi import aws:s3/bucket:Bucket infra-logs company-infra-logs
```

when **infra-logs** is the resource name for your Pulumi program, and **company-infra-logs** is the bucket name.

In your case, when importing a Target Group an ARN is expected instead of the resource name.

I've tried fetching a target group like this:

```
pulumi import aws:alb/targetGroup:TargetGroup test-tg <ARN>
```

And it worked for me.

Couple of key notes for you to validate:

1. Make sure that the ARN is copied correctly, the ARN is built as follows:

   **arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing::<ACCOUNT_ID>:targetgroup/<TARGET_GROUP_NAME>/**
2. Make sure your pulumi stack is in the same region as your target group
3. Make sure your AWS credentials are configured properly (you might be on the wrong profile, or wrong account)